# What are the available mechanisms to hang pictures on the fridge?

Tags: prints, display

In the past, I have used adhesive tapes and fridge magnets of various shapes and sizes to hang pictures on the fridge wall. The magnets seem to be not so powerful and every now and then I have to rearrange the pictures. Applying direct adhesive tapes on the photos themselves makes the removal messy and leaves adhesive stains on the pictures/fridge wall.

What I want is an easy mechanism to hang pictures on the fridge wall, and easy removal when I want to replace existing photos with a fresh batch. Please suggest.

Comment: Try diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried simply, more powerful magnets? They are readily available and would seemingly do the trick.

Comment: @dpolitt - thanks for introducing the diySE. Did not know it existed until now!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [self adhesive magnetic tape](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Magnetic-Craft-Adhesive-1-5mm-adhesive/dp/B001DT262C/ref=pd_cp_k_h_b_cs_0).

This has the advantage of being able to apply it on the back of the photo where you want to make it as secure as possible. It is also very thin and relatively cheap (depending how often you wanted to replace pictures)

Comment: This looks like at interesting product. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [Blu-Tack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack), or a similar putty adhesive. These have plenty of grip and leave no residue.

You can also try better magnets as @dpollitt suggests. The kind you want are called ['rare earth' magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare-earth_magnet) and are super strong, but harder to find. Also, keep them far away from any recording media, memory cards, etc.